# Flex Problem Enabling and Disabling Button in List

Tags: apache-flex

I have a list with a dataprovider, it lists out buttons encapsulated in an item renderer.  All I want it to do is have a skin that it changes to when it is clicked. I can get this to happen, but then it just goes back to its up state. I want it to stick on the down state, which I have to do by disabling the button.

So I tried this:

```
buttonList.selectedItem.enabled = false; 

for(var i:Number = 0; i< buttonList.numChildren; i++)
{
   var loopBtn = buttonList.getChildAt(i);

if(loopBtn != buttonList.selectedItem)
{
  loopBtn.enabled = true;
}

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a toggle button here?

```
<mx:Button toggle="true" ... />
```

At least it would stay in the down state after being pressed.

Comment: Thanks you, that fixed the problem with it not staying in the down state. But now all of them stay in that state unless I click them again. I feel like this shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You need a static variable 'selectedButton' in the class those buttons that retains the latest selected button.

on click you set the selectedButton back to non-selected before selecting the new one.

HTH